# Serializing large object graph leads to endless loop in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize a large object graph with protobuf-net, around 2.5 million items, but the application seems to get stuck in an endless loop. Memory consumption pulsates between 20-40 GB and it uses 100% of one CPU core.

Serializing a graph of around 2 million objects works fine and results in an 850 MB file.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the problem or do I have to split the tree in smaller pieces before serializing it?

I apologize that my classes are a bit complex but I thought it could be part of the problem. I am using version 2.0.0.668 of protobuf-net.
Each RoutingNode contains around 50 subnodes.

```
[ProtoContract()]
public class Tree
{
    public Tree() { }

    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public byte[] SomeValues { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public RoutingNode Root { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true), ProtoInclude(101, typeof(RoutingNode)), ProtoInclude(102, typeof(LeafNode))]
public abstract class TreeNode
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] Hash { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    public TreeNode() { }
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class RoutingNode : TreeNode
{
    public RoutingNode() { }

    static Random r = new Random();

    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    private List<TreeNode> _subTree = new List<TreeNode>();

    public RoutingNode Parent { get; set; }

    public void AddNode(TreeNode node)
    {
        if (_subTree.Count < 50 || node is LeafNode)
        {
            _subTree.Add(node);
        }
        else
        {
            ((RoutingNode)_subTree[r.Next(_subTree.Count - 1)]).AddNode(node);
        }

    }

    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    protected void OnDeserialized()
    {
        if (_subTree == null) _subTree = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (TreeNode node in _subTree)
        {
            if (node is RoutingNode)
            {
                (node as RoutingNode).Parent = this;
            }
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class LeafNode : TreeNode
{
    public LeafNode() { }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int[] SomeValues { get; set; }
}
```

### SAMPLE PROGRAM

```
var tree = new Tree();

        tree.Root = new RoutingNode();

        var r = new Random();

        for (uint i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[200];
            r.NextBytes(hash);
            tree.Root.AddNode(new RoutingNode() { Hash = hash, Id = i });
        }

        for (uint j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[200];
            r.NextBytes(hash);

            var node = new RoutingNode() { Hash = hash, Id = j };
            for (uint i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                hash = new byte[200];
                r.NextBytes(hash);
                node.AddNode(new LeafNode() { Hash = hash, Id = i });                    
            }
            tree.Root.AddNode(node);
        }

        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("test.tmp"))
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, tree);
```

Comment: Is the tree a pure tree? or is it ever circular? Do you have anything I can use to reproduce it? I see that `Parent` isn't serialized, but is it possible that a `TreeNode` directly or indirectly contains itself? (note: it should detect that automatically)

Comment: A node never contains itself, all nodes in the tree should be unique. I can probably create a small test program that can recreate the problem.

Comment: I added a small sample program to the original question. I run it on my machine with 16 GB of ram but the memory utilization never goes over 80% and the app fluctuates between 4.5 - 8 GB when serializing. The app takes around 1.9 GB of ram before serialization starts.

Comment: k; I don't have an immediate answer, but I will investigate

Comment: How is the investigation going? I hope you saw that I updated the question @marc with a sample program.

Comment: @marc - were you ever able to resolve the issues in this question? I'm having very similar issue: large object graph, memory fills and fluctuates, endless loop, no exceptions

Comment: @ringstaff I ended up writing my own serialization as I couldn't get it to work otherwise.